# Workflow not kicking off on view change

Tags: infopath, designer-workflow, forms-services

I have a scenario where I am using InfoPath form with 4 different views-

1. Initial view
2. Team view
3. Acceptance view
4. Final view

Steps I followed-

1. I have a field in form which changes views accordingly.
2. I have implemented a workflow , where on every change of view an email will be sent to certain groups.
3. When initial form is submitted at first an email is sent to a permission group which I declared as variable in workflow.
4. Once the form is viewed by group they will submit the form (they will see `View 2`)
5. On submit an email is sent to initiator saying group has submitted the form and once he clicks on the link provided in mail it will show him `View 3` with two options one is `Submit` and other is `Reevaluate`.
6. If he clicks on `reevaluate` it should send email back to the group with `View 2`.
7. Everything works fine if it is straightforward.
8. But once I am on email 3 where initiator asks for Reevaluate it is showing completed and no mail is sent.

Please check the figure I am posting and let me know if am doing something wrong in terms of workflow.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why there are two conditions for View 1? The first 1 does nothing, then at the last step there are actions. What's happening currently at your workflow is that during reevaluation, it is going inside the view 1 condition which does nothing.

If the first view 1 condition is for the initial submission, put the actions inside it (the 3 THEN). Now for reevaluate, which I guess is the last view 1 condition, put another condition to satisfy like, Setview = 1 AND Status = "Reevaluate" so it will go directly to that condition step. Put the actions inside that step.

Comment: Found that mekalikot and fixed it.thanks for the needy guidance.